# Questions appearing on Twitter

Tags: discussion, scope

I saw a tweet from here yesterday about a question.  I had answered the question so I re-tweeted it.  Today I received a notification that someone had re-tweeted my tweet.

Is this the result of an automated interface between the two sites?  If so, is there a non-confidential threshold governing what gets tweeted? Or alternatively is everything posted on Twitter?

Last question: does the tweet get 'bumped' or re-tweeted for answers?  Or just the original question?

Adding: I'm interested in the tweet that originated here; not the one that got re-tweeted.

Answer (score 2):

Without saying who retweeted your tweet, it's hard to tell ;)

twitter.com/stacktravel is our 'official' account, and it automatically tweets new open questions after a short while - to allow for edits, closure etc.

The retweet? Who did it? Stacktravel or someone else? If stacktravel, that may be new, but if someone else they just 'chose' to ;)

As far as I'm aware there's no extra twitter features apart from just the initial tweet.

Comment: edited for clarity